# Finding which function throws an exception in VC++6

Tags: c++, visual-studio, visual-c++-6

I'm working on a legacy codebase in vc++6. There is a bug where an exception is thrown but it is silenced which causes issues higher up the stack. The bug occurs in production and I'm unable to repro the bug in house (I can't update the production code and log the error).

```
HRESULT legacyCall()
{
   try
   {
      return FunctionThatCallsManyFunctions();
   }
   catch( _com_error e)
   {
      return E_FAIL;
   }

}
```

I'm trying to find which method calls throw exceptions by static analysis however, there are too many abstractions and lines of code to sift through. I'm wondering if there is a compiler flag or a methodology to finding where the exceptions are thrown?

Comment: visual studio allows to set breakpoint when exception is thrown. But that need local reproduction...

Comment: And I thought we were using ancient products (VS 2008) :) :)

Comment: 1. Find the `comdef.h` header. 2. Fudge it by `#define`'ing `_com_error`, `_com_raise_error` and such to other identifiers. `#undef` them at the end. 4. Compile your code and see what breaks -- that's what's trying to throw the exception! 5. Don't forget to restore `comdef.h` :)

Comment: In Debug mode try to make break point(F9) at start of the function and go line by line using F10 or more depth using F11. 
If the code is too long you have to go long and make break point at some interval to continue .

Comment: Alternative technique if the compilation just blows up completely after the above tinkering: instead of breaking the `_com` stuff, `__declspec(deprecated)` it.

Comment: @Quentin I think your method could work. What is a modification that would make the caller fail to compile?

Comment: @Mozly what I've said: use `#define` to sneakily rename the type in the system header only. The caller will still try to use `_com_error`, which won't exist. This might not be useful if there are a lot of other uses though. Deprecation will produce warnings instead.

Comment: I've done `#define _com_error int` but there are no compilation errors.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks to @Quentin I found out that `_com_error` and its accessors are defined in `comdef.h`. A _com_error can be thrown by calling `_com_issue_errorex` or `_com_issue_error` or `_com_raise_error`.

The reason I couldn't find any exception throws in the source is because it is implicitly defined in a autogenerated file called myCOMlibrary.tli (type library implementation). This file is created by a COM wizard and wraps all the calls the COM libraries and throws an error if the call returns anything but success.

Knowing this I was able to grep for the above mentioned functions and find all the places in the code where a _com_error is thrown.